# Cube doesnt show all the faces when orbiting, depends on a viewer angle

Tags: modeling

The columns of the building show its faces only if orbiting in Textured mode. The same is in BGEngine, the 1st view player  should run around the column to see appearing and disappearing faces.

I have already unticked Backface Culling in Shading, but it stays the same. 
Multitextured shading

Just "diffuse" Material colour

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

selected the object, edit mode, select all, hit T, to the shading/uv's tab, scrolled it a bit down hit either recalculate (should fix it instantly) or hit flip direction (this is best if you only select the faces that needs to be flipped).